# Separate Web API call from ASP.NET MVC Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

I am using ASP.NET MVC (.NET 6) project and from many of the controllers endpoints I do separate web API calls, like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
   MyObj externalApiResponse = await myService.GetData();
   return View(externalApiResponse);

}
```

Since, invoking the controller endpoint through the view is one http request and the separate web API call that I make is another, external http request, I was wondering what is the case with the HttpContext object. Are the 2 http request sharing the same HttpContext/ HttpContextAccessor?

Because, I want both the external API calls and the MVC controller http request to have attached the same item in the header.

From my experiment, I created a singleton class:

public class HttpRequestManager
{
private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

```
    private const string myKey = "my-personal-key";

    public HttpRequestManager(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public string GenerateKey()
    {
        string text = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext!.Request.Headers.Add(myKey , text);
        return text;
    }
```

Which I injected in one of my controllers and I call GenerateKey() in the constructor like this:

```
public class MyController
{
   private HttpRequestManager _manager;

   public MyController(HttpRequestManager manager) 
   {
     _manager = manager
     _manager.GenerateToken()
   }
}
```

... when debugging the external API call, in the request headers the header exists even there.

Is this the normal behavior?
Edit: ... For the external API calls I use HttpClient injected in the DI container, so I thought the HttpClient would create separate http context.

Comment: Yes,  when you make a separate web API call from within a controller action, it will be a new HTTP request with its own HttpContext.